# Returning SQLAlchemy ORM Mapped Class Check Constraint

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Given the following table:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Text, Integer, CheckConstraint
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()

class TestTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'my_test_table'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Text, CheckConstraint("name IN ('abc', 'def', 'ghi')"))
```

Is it possible to return a list of values in the check constraint?

My guess is that it would look something like this:

```
list_of_possible_names = TestTable.name.checkconstraint.values
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'd have to parse the check constraint text yourself but you can get it with something like:

[Inspector.get_check_constraints](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/reflection.html#sqlalchemy.engine.reflection.Inspector.get_check_constraints)

```py
from sqlalchemy import inspect

# engine = ...

from sqlalchemy import Column, Text, Integer, CheckConstraint
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()

class TestTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'my_test_table'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Text, CheckConstraint("name IN ('abc', 'def', 'ghi')"))

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)


insp = inspect(engine)
for ck in insp.get_check_constraints(TestTable.__table__):
    print(ck)
```

```
{'name': 'my_test_table_name_check', 'sqltext': "name = ANY (ARRAY['abc'::text, 'def'::text, 'ghi'::text])"}
```